# Keep game running when swich browser tab

Tags: actionscript-3

I work on an idle game. When I switch browser tab or do something else the game lose focus. I want to keep the game running when I switch browser tab or do something else. I searched on google but I didn't find an answer.

How can I do that?(sorry for my english)

Comment: Well, it still does run while not visible. You might not get as many frames per second as normal, but the game will run.

Comment: and to keep normal frames per second?

Comment: i have some variables depending on this

Comment: Try setting `stage.frameRate` whenever you see it drop. I don't have other ideas right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control it. And it's a bad idea to rely on stable frame times anyway. And not just because the speed of a the PC can affect the frame rate.

What you usually do instead is using delta time:

- [Is this a good implementation of the gameloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010803/is-this-a-good-implementation-of-the-gameloop)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_timing

Basically on every tick/frame you measure how much time passed by since the last tick/frame and then calculate progress depending on that duration.

EDIT:

To answer your first question, you can use the same method for frames as for coordinates. The main difference is that when you use frames, you actually work with integers while displayobject coordinates are using floating point values. Since integers are too inaccurate for the method described, you should use an internal floating point (":Number") variable, apply all calculations on that floating point variable and finally use Math.round() on the value to get the actual frame number.

EDIT 2:

Here some **very basic untested** code:

```
[variable definition]
var floatingNumberFrame:Number=1;

[code in loop]
floatingNumberFrame+=speed*deltaTime;
if(floatingNumberFrame>=101){
    floatingNumberFrame=floatingNumberFrame%100;
}
theMovie.gotoAndStop(Math.round(floatingNumberFrame));
```

Comment: [implementation of the gameloop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010803/is-this-a-good-implementation-of-the-gameloop)                                                                           I did like in answer. In function update game state how I can do? something like this?? timeC.gotoAndStop(timeC.currentFrame+SOMETHING);

Comment: timeC is the movieclip

Comment: timeC is like a loading bar....evry time timeC.currentFrame==100 something hepend....how can I implement for this movieclip?

Comment: ca you give me an example please?

Comment: That sounds like a different question and I am not sure it can be answered without seing your actual code. With the method being used, it possible to for example move from frame 98 to frame 102 if the browser slept. You'd need to do a > 100 check. In the next step http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#modulo might be helpfull.

Comment: (enter_frame function) var now = new Date().getTime();
      var delta = now - _lastTime;
      _lastTime = now;
   trace(now);
   updateGameState(delta/1000);
  }
  function updateGameState(timeElapsed:Number):void {
   if(timeC.currentFrame==100)
   {
    timeC.gotoAndStop(1);
   }
   
      timeC.gotoAndStop(timeC.currentFrame+1);
  }

Comment: [this is the game](https://www.fgl.com/view_game.php?from=dev&game_id=34057)  moviclip is the blue bar.

Comment: The link most likely only works for you, since you need to be logged in for it. I am leaving in a few minutes, not sure if I'll be able to look into this any further today.